# How do you override the string representation the HTML helper methods use for a model’s properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The html helper methods check the ViewDataDictionary for a value. The value can either be in the dictionary or in the Model, as a property. To extract the value, an internal sealed class named the ViewDataEvaluator uses PropertyDescriptor to get the value. Then, Convert.ToString() is called to convert the object returned to a string.

#### Desired code in Controller action

The controller action should only populate the Model, not format it (formatting the model is global).

#### Desired code in View

The view can render a HTML textbox and extract the string representation of the property with this line of code:

```
<%=Html.TextBox(“Date”) %>
<%=Html.TextBox(“Time”) %>
<%=Html.TextBox(“UnitPrice”) %>
```

#### Binding Model's Property to HtmlHelper.TextBox()

For the textbox’s value, the UnitPrice property’s value from the model instance is converted to a string. I need to override this behavior with my own conversion to a string, which is per property – not per type. For example, I need a different string representation of a **decimal** for UnitPrice and another string representation of a **decimal** for UnitQuantity.

For example, I need to format the UnitPrice's decimal precision based on the market.

```
string decimalPlaces = ViewData.Model.Precision.ToString ();
<%=Html.TextBox(“UnitPrice”, ViewData.Model.TypeName.UnitPrice.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces)) %>
```

#### 2-way databinding please

Just like the IModelBinder is the *Parse* for each property of the model, I need a *Format* for each property, kinda like Windows Forms [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding_events.aspx), but based on the model instead of the control. This would enable the model to round-trip and have proper formatting. I would prefer a design where I could override the default formatting. In addition, my model is in a separate assembly, so attributed properties specifying a formatter are not an option.

Please note I need **property specific** formatting for a model, not **type specific** formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to specify a format with the helpers themselves. The approach you've taken will work. Another approach is to add the value pre-formatted into the `ModelState`.

**EDIT**: Are you sure you even want to format a text input with the currency? For example, what you would see in the input is:

```
<input type="text" name="UnitPrice" value="$1.23" />
```

When you post that back to the server, we won't understand it. Instead, I'd put the currency symbol *outside* of the text input. For example:

```
$<%= Html.TextBox("UnitPrice") %>
```

I'm sure there's an easy method to render "$" without hard-coding it so it's localizable, but I don't know what it is offhand.

**EDIT AGAIN**
A comment from a developer on my team:

> Well, to be fair, this isn’t that bad.
>   Often when you format a number or a
>   date it’s still understandable coming
>   back in.  For example, padding a
>   number (like a ZIP code) to 5 digits,
>   padding a decimal to the hundredths,
>   formatting a date to be yyyy-mm-dd,
>   etc. will come in just fine.  Adding
>   extra characters like currency symbols
>   will break, but normally input fields
>   don’t take or display currency symbols
>   anyway – it’s implied.

Comment: I'm going to call a static helper to pre-format the Model into ModelState on ever action that loads the model. As you say, this will work for now.

Comment: Also, there are many cases where you need to specify a specific format/parse - for example, a yy-mm-dd will not parse correctly: you need to call DateTime.ParseExact(...) on Parse, and DateTime.ToString(...) on Format